# How to set binding in xaml to my own variable

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have an object in the code:

```
public  class UserLogin
    {
        bool _IsUserLogin = false;

        public bool IsUserLogin
        {
            get { return _IsUserLogin; }
            set { _IsUserLogin = value; }
        }

        public UserLogin()
        {
            _IsUserLogin = false;
        }
    }
    ....
    public static UserLogin LoginState;
    .....
    LoginState = new UserLogin();
```

And I need to set bindings to Button.IsEnabled property. I.e. when user not login yet - some buttons are disabled. How can this been done? I have try in xaml:

```
<Button DataContext="LoginState" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsUserLogin}">
```

but, this dos't work and OutputWindow says: System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsUserLogin' property not found on 'object'.
I also have try to set Button.DataContext property to LoginState in the code, but have XamlParseException. I also read this one [[WPF - Binding in XAML to an object created in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829758/wpf-binding-in-xaml-to-an-object-created-in-the-code-behind][1]) but still can't set bindings.

[1]: [WPF - Binding in XAML to an object created in the code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829758/wpf-binding-in-xaml-to-an-object-created-in-the-code-behind). Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You get the XamlException cause the compiler doesn´t find an (XAML)-Element with the name "LoginState".

Set the DataContext of the button in procedural code. Then it should work.

```
public void SetDataContextOfButton() {
  UserLogin login = new UserLogin();
  button.DataContext = login; //Assumes that you name your Button in XAML with x:Name="button"
}
```

Comment: I'am an idiot, I was try to set DataContext of the button before  InitializeComponent();
Thanks!